# Javascript to load putty to a specific ssh host

Tags: javascript, shell, putty, wsh

I am trying to create a website that has links and depending on those links it will load putty  with an ssh connection to a specific host. ( this is to be used internally and ie 6)

so far i have ignore the host

```
<script language="javascript">
function connection(host) {
  oShell = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
  oShell.Run("putty.exe -ssh" + host + "22");
}

</script>



<a href="javascript:connection('@1.1.1.1')"> Connection 1 </a>
```

Comment: Why not do something more standard and use an `ssh:` protocol handler?  https://kb.op5.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=688361

Comment: i need it to specifically load it through putty

Comment: Right, go configure everyone's machines to use PuTTY as a handler for `ssh:`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to perform what you need

```
<script language="javascript">
function connection(host) {
  var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
  oShell.Run('"c:\\Archivos de programa\\PuTTY\\putty.exe" -ssh '+ host +' 22');
  }

</script>

<a href="javascript:connection('@1.1.1.1')"> Connection 1 </a>
```

I needed to pass the location of putty executable (with escaped chars) as well as adding some spaces missing in your code (afer -ssh and before 22). As long as putty can run standalone perhaps you can place putty.exe in a network shared location so *everyone* is able to launch it and most important: there is a consistent location to all users.

Take a look also to the [command-line options of putty](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7.1) which can be also interesting for you.